# I'm learning C programming recursion and doing an activity but I'm stuck

Tags: c, recursion

Maybe it's a simple question. I just started learning C alone.
There is a break point 
"if" in sumOfDigits function.
But I have no idea why it is a breakpoint...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sumOfDigits(int);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int N;

    scanf("%d", &N);
    N = sumOfDigits(N);
    printf("%d", N);

    return 0;
}

int sumOfDigits (int num)
{
    if (num<10)
        return num;
    else
    {
        num = sumOfDigits(num)/10;
    return num + num%10;
}
}
```

It shows me like this.

Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1

Comment: Do you know what a breakpoint is?

Comment: It's only a breakpoint in your IDE. It helps you debugging, following the instructions one by one and seeing how the variables change.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
num = sumOfDigits(num)/10;
```

to

```
num = sumOfDigits(num/10);
```

The num variable in your example isn't being decreased, the function will call itself until the memory runs out, and you will have a segmentation fault error.